# Getting an error when running project with metal

Tags: ios, metal

I am following Ray Wenderlich's tutorial for drawing 2D objects in Metal with Swift. I followed his steps and I have no syntax errors. But when I run the app I get the following error:

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/bin/metallib failed with exit code 1

I searched online and the error occurs because apple changed some framework from ios 8 to ios 9. Because this tutorial was created during ios 8 and I am using ios 9 the error occurs. I tried switching the porject's target to ios 8, but still the same problem. Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post your code reproducing the issue? Otherwise we have no clue of what it looks like.

Comment: Are you using a real device to test? You need a real device for Metal.

Comment: Its not the code that is causing the issue. The project just won't run because of some setting that apple has changed from ios 8 to ios 9

Comment: Yes I am using my iphone 5 to test

Comment: Metal is not supported on iPhone 5.

Comment: Oh wow did not know that. Thank you!

Comment: you can run your `Metal` projects on a OS X target. check [my blog](http://mhorga.org/) for 2D examples (parts 3 and 5).